# Images on my responsive website show low quality on phone

Tags: html, image, mobile, blurry

I am making a responsive website for work and designed a nice **294x104 (px) vectored logo**. I have a .PNG, a .SVG, and an .EPS file for it.

When displayed on the website, the same image is shrunk to *115x40 (px)*. It looks great on my desktop, however when I load it on my Android 980p screen, I noticed the image looks very blurred and distorted.

I've been messing around with viewport, and this fits my website perfect:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

But it is still blurred. And then, when I resize the vectored image down to 115x40 px, it appears blurry still. I want it to be sharp as can be on both desktop and mobile. 
What are some suggestions for doing this?

---

[image: Desktop]
[image: Mobile]

Comment: have you tried using CSS, namely, the `@media handheld` to force the image to retain it's size?

Comment: I do make use of @media but how would I go about forcing it to retain it's size? Does the mobile phone change the size? Sorry, I am not too swift with mobile browsers. If you could make an answer with your suggestions it might work out.

Comment: I'd think you would just be able to do, `@media handheld  img#myimg { width: 294px; height: 104px; }`